# version number inside AssemblyInfo.cs update outside visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

Is it possible to update the version number(AssemblyVersion("1.0.2.1")) insdie AssemblyInfo.cs outside visual studio???(Maybe using a script or a batch file)

Answer (score 2):

I have used [UpdateVersion](http://code.mattgriffith.net/UpdateVersion/) in the past to update the version number as part of a build script before. If you use subversion you can also use SubWCRev.exe from TortoiseSVN to update the version number to include the SVN revision number.

Answer (score 2):

It can also be done from MSBuild..

Check out the AssemblyInfo task here: 
[MSBuild tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/)

We use it from CruiseControl.net it's very straightforward to use.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a PowerShell script that would write the version number out to "AssemblyVersion.cs", like this:

```
// DO NOT EDIT
// Generated by UpdateVersion.ps1.

[AssemblyVersion("1.0.2.1")]
```

The version number was updated in all projects/assemblies at once this way.  The canonical number was stored elsewhere.

It's trivial to write, but varies depending on your exact needs, so I won't try to post it here.

Comment: any sample of UpdateVersion.ps1 ?? What I need install for use Powershell scripts ?? I have Winxp sp2.

Comment: @alha: I don't have access to it any more, sorry. Luckily this isn't a difficult problem.

Comment: SetVersion.ps1 - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/04/21/powershell-script-to-batch-update-assemblyinfo-cs-with-new-version.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use any search and replace tool or write one yourself.

For the current porject (that is built with msbuild) I'm using a custom build step (self written as it is small and simple) that searches for AssemblyVersion and replaces that in the AssemblyInfo.cs files.